# Creating a raised card effect in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, drop-shadow

How can this be done? It looks like the invitations are raised. Is it with drop shadow or another tool? I'd like to be able to do this in Illustrator.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like drop shadows.

Comment: Why would you use Illustrator for real looking photos like this??

Answer (score 1):

Illustrator has a (raster) drop shadow effect:

Choose `Effect > Stylize > Drop Shadow`

[image]

You'll also want to ensure the `Document Raster Effects Setting` is correct:

[image]

[image]

This is a **raster** effect and will create embedded raster images upon output or flattening.